# chart.js with xAaxis timeline

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart

I'm using chart.js to create a chart with a timeline as a x-axis. But how it works ? I don't find any way how to. I have unix timestamp values and values to this timestamps. How to handle this?

Comment: Using the beta version 2.0 helps me out of this problem